# Right-to-left input field - Tag-it jquery UI plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, arabic, tag-it

Tag-it is a jquery UI plugin that allows assigning tags from front end, exactly like tags system in stackoverflow. 
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

In fact, after calling required scripts inside my `<head>`, I just put in my code source:

```
<ul id="myTags">
</ul>
```

And call the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });
</script>
```

After execution, the final code source is (Let's say I have inserted one tag):

```
<ul id="myTags" class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
   <li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
       <span class="tagit-label">tag1</span>
       <a class="tagit-close">
       <span class="text-icon">×</span>
       <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
       </a>
       <input dir="rtl" type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="tag1" name="tages[]">
  </li>
  <li class="tagit-new">
  <input dir="rtl" type="text" class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to put `dir="rtl"` in the jquery script of tag-it inside the `input`, also I tried to put `dir="rtl"` in `<ul>`, but to no avail. I am sure that customizing this plugin so that it makes the input from right to left is beyond my area of knowledge, that's why I am asking you usual help, which is always appreciated.

How can I make the input field of tag-it work from right to left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a class in css file:

```
ul.tagit li {
/* add this lines */
float: right;
list-style: disc outside none;
}
```

It will make your tags to right when you try to add in a text box.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer to this matter, I will test and come back to give a feedback.

Comment: i have change the css id class name as per your html UL id. please check it.

Comment: I have edited taking into consideration the CSS file provided with plugin.

Comment: is it solved your problem? please let me know. thanks in advance.